# Solr_thumbnail doesn't work properly with a url variable in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, thumbnails, sorl-thumbnail

On the side of views.py, I get the external image url from the database and send it to template:

```
for variable in our_list:
    thumbnail = ExternalAPICall(id=variable[0], 'thumbnail') #returns http://img48.imagesuit.gp/423ad3af.png
    ...
    variable.append(thumbnail)
    ...
context = {
            ...
            'our_list': our_list,
            ...
          }
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

On the side of template I load thumbnail and decorate  with thumbnail operator:

```
{% load thumbnail %}
...
{% for id, ... thumb ... in our_list %}
      ...
      {% thumbnail thumb "100x100" crop="center" as im %}
      <img alt="" src="{{ im.url }}" width="164" style="max-width:175px;border:0;min-height:auto;outline:none;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:bottom" class="CToWUd">
      {% endthumbnail %}
{% endfor %}
```

And it renders empty line instead of the line of images.

What's wrong?

Comment: It's not evident from your code what the contents of `variable` actually are. Are you sure that `thumb` in your template is actually the URL to the image?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, I did an output of the static url from this element earlier.

Comment: Content is a list of lists.

Comment: Try setting `THUMBNAIL_DEBUG = True` in your settings, so that the tag doesn't fail silently and reports errors.

Comment: I fixed some code nuances, see update.

Comment: @solarissmoke It's fired an OSError OSError at /offers/ [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/username/projectname/media'

Comment: Looks like you found the problem. Make sure that the directory exists and is writeable (you need permissions `rwx`) by the process that runs wsgi/django. Sorl must be able to write the generated thumbnail file to the local file storage, even if the source is on a different web server.